# Proper way of using mongodb connection or express.js across multiple node.js file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to split my node.js file into multiple file like:

- user.js for dealing with user database CRUD
- group.js for dealing with group database CRUD
- database.js for initializing database
- restful.js for initializing express.js

What my concern is whether this is a common or good practice.

So the following files are after splitting:

**app.js**

```
require('./restful');
require('./database');
```

**config.js**

```
module.exports = function(){

database :{
   username: "mark",
   password: "pass",
   host: "127.0.0.1",
   port: "27017",
   name: "mydb"
};
```

**database.js**

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var url = 'mongodb://'+ config.database.username+ ':' + config.database.password + '@' + config.database.host + ':' + config.database.port + '/' + config.database.name;

var Database = function() {
    var db;

    // always return the singleton instance, if it has been initialised once already.
    if (Database.prototype._singletonInstance) {
        return Database.prototype._singletonInstance;
    }    

    this.getDatabase = function() {
         return db;
    }

    this.get = this.getDatabase;

    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, result) {
        if(err || result === undefined || result === null) {
              throw err;
        } else {
              db = result;
        }
    });    

    Database.prototype._singletonInstance = this;    
};

new Database();

console.log('MongoDb set up OK!');

exports.Database = Database;
};
```

**restful.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var restful_express = express();
restful_express.use(bodyParser());

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'token');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-XSRF-TOKEN, Last-Event-ID, Content-Language, Accept-Language, Accept');
    res.header('X-XSS-Protection', 0);
    next();
}

restful_express.use(allowCrossDomain);

restful_express.listen(process.env.PORT || 7272, function(err) {
       winlog.info('ExpressJs listening at 7272');    
});  

var Restful = function() {

    // always return the singleton instance, if it has been initialised once already.
    if (Restful.prototype._singletonInstance) {
        return Restful.prototype._singletonInstance;      
    }    

    this.getRestful = function() {
         return restful_express;       
    }

    Restful.prototype._singletonInstance = this;      
};

new Restful();

console.log('Express.js Restful set up OK!');

exports.Restful = Restful;
```

**user.js**

```
var config = require('./config');
var database = require('./database');
var db = database.Database();
var restful = require('./restful').Restful().getRestful();

module.exports = function(){

    restful.get('/getUser/:email', function(req, res) {

            db.get().collection("user").findOne({email:req.param('email')}, function(err, result) {

                   if(result) {          
                      res.send({name:result.name});
                   } else {
                      res.statusCode = 400;
                      res.send({msg:'Email not found'});         
                   }
            });
    });
});
```

**group.js**

```
var config = require('./config');
var database = require('./database');
var db = database.Database();
var restful = require('./restful').Restful().getRestful();

module.exports = function(){

    restful.get('/getGroup/:name', function(req, res) {

            db.get().collection("group").findOne({name:req.param('name')}, function(err, result) {

                   if(result) {                        
                      res.send({name:result.name});  
                   } else {
                      res.statusCode = 400;
                      res.send({msg:'Group not found'});         
                   }
            }); 
    });

});
```

So database.js can be simplified to:

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var db;
var url = 'mongodb://'+ config.database.username+ ':' + config.database.password + '@' + config.database.host + ':' + config.database.port + '/' + config.database.name;

module.exports = function(){
    initDb : function () {
        mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, result) {
            if(err || result === undefined || result === null) {
                  throw err;
            } else {
                  db = result;
            }
        });         
    },

    getDb : function () {
        if(db === null || db === undefined) {
            this.initDb();
        }   
        return db;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just an absolutely legal way. But quite over complicated one.

`module` is a singleton by default. Regardless how many times you call `require('some_module');` it's scaffolding code is executed only once. Try the following code in REPL

```
//index.js
var i = 0;
i ++;
exports.show = function(){
   return i;
};
exports.increment = function(){  
   return i++;
};
```

then in REPL

```
> var one = require('./index.js');
> one.show();
  1
> var two = require('./index.js');
> two.show();
  1 
> one.increment();
  2
> two.show();
  2
```